# Enabling ExpandPersistentVolumes

Tags: kubernetes

I need to resize a bunch of PVCs. It seems the easiest way to do it is through
the ExpandPersistentVolumes feature. I am however having trouble getting the
configuration to cooperate.

The `ExpandPersistentVolumes` feature gate is set in kubelet on all three
masters, as shown:

(output trimmed to relevant bits for sanity)

```
$ parallel-ssh -h /tmp/masters -P "ps aux | grep feature"
172.20.53.249: root     15206  7.4  0.5 619888 83952 ?        Ssl  19:52   0:02 /opt/kubernetes/bin/kubelet  --feature-gates=ExpandPersistentVolumes=true,ExperimentalCriticalPodAnnotation=true
[1] 12:53:08 [SUCCESS] 172.20...
172.20.58.111: root     17798  4.5  0.5 636280 87328 ?        Ssl  19:51   0:04 /opt/kubernetes/bin/kubelet --feature-gates=ExpandPersistentVolumes=true,ExperimentalCriticalPodAnnotation=true
[2] 12:53:08 [SUCCESS] 172.20...
172.20.53.240: root      9287  4.0  0.5 645276 90528 ?        Ssl  19:50   0:06 /opt/kubernetes/bin/kubelet --feature-gates=ExpandPersistentVolumes=true,ExperimentalCriticalPodAnnotation=true
[3] 12:53:08 [SUCCESS] 172.20..
```

The apiserver has the `PersistentVolumeClaimResize` admission controller, as shown:

```
$ kubectl --namespace=kube-system get pod -o yaml | grep -i admission                                                                                                                                                           
    /usr/local/bin/kube-apiserver --admission-control=Initializers,NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,PersistentVolumeLabel,DefaultStorageClass,DefaultTolerationSeconds,MutatingAdmissionWebhook,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,NodeRestriction,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,ResourceQuota
    /usr/local/bin/kube-apiserver --admission-control=Initializers,NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,PersistentVolumeLabel,DefaultStorageClass,DefaultTolerationSeconds,MutatingAdmissionWebhook,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,NodeRestriction,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,ResourceQuota
    /usr/local/bin/kube-apiserver --admission-control=Initializers,NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,PersistentVolumeLabel,DefaultStorageClass,DefaultTolerationSeconds,MutatingAdmissionWebhook,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,NodeRestriction,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,ResourceQuota
```

However, when I create or edit a storage class to add `allowVolumeExpansion`, 
it is removed on save. For example:

```
$ cat new-sc.yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    k8s-addon: storage-aws.addons.k8s.io
  name: gp2-2
  selfLink: /apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses/gp2
parameters:
  encrypted: "true"
  kmsKeyId: arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:<omitted>
  type: gp2
  zone: us-west-2a
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
reclaimPolicy: Delete
allowVolumeExpansion: true

$ kubectl create -f new-sc.yaml
storageclass "gp2-2" created

$ kubectl get sc gp2-2 -o yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-05-22T20:00:17Z
  labels:
    k8s-addon: storage-aws.addons.k8s.io
  name: gp2-2
  resourceVersion: "2546166"
  selfLink: /apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses/gp2-2
  uid: <omitted>
parameters:
  encrypted: "true"
  kmsKeyId: arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:<omitted>
  type: gp2
  zone: us-west-2a
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
reclaimPolicy: Delete
```

What am I missing? What is erasing this key from my storageclass configuration?

**EDIT:** Here is the command used by the kube-apiserver pods. It does not say anything about feature gates. The cluster was launched using Kops.

```
- /bin/sh
    - -c
    - mkfifo /tmp/pipe; (tee -a /var/log/kube-apiserver.log < /tmp/pipe & ) ; exec
      /usr/local/bin/kube-apiserver --address=127.0.0.1 --admission-control=Initializers,NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,PersistentVolumeLabel,DefaultStorageClass,DefaultTolerationSeconds,MutatingAdmissionWebhook,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,NodeRestriction,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,ResourceQuota
      --allow-privileged=true --anonymous-auth=false --apiserver-count=3 --authorization-mode=RBAC
      --basic-auth-file=/srv/kubernetes/basic_auth.csv --client-ca-file=/srv/kubernetes/ca.crt
      --cloud-provider=aws --etcd-cafile=/srv/kubernetes/ca.crt --etcd-certfile=/srv/kubernetes/etcd-client.pem
      --etcd-keyfile=/srv/kubernetes/etcd-client-key.pem --etcd-servers-overrides=/events#https://127.0.0.1:4002
      --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:4001 --insecure-port=8080 --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,Hostname,ExternalIP
      --proxy-client-cert-file=/srv/kubernetes/apiserver-aggregator.cert --proxy-client-key-file=/srv/kubernetes/apiserver-aggregator.key
      --requestheader-allowed-names=aggregator --requestheader-client-ca-file=/srv/kubernetes/apiserver-aggregator-ca.cert
      --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra- --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
      --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User --secure-port=443 --service-cluster-ip-range=100.64.0.0/13
      --storage-backend=etcd3 --tls-cert-file=/srv/kubernetes/server.cert --tls-private-key-file=/srv/kubernetes/server.key
      --token-auth-file=/srv/kubernetes/known_tokens.csv --v=1 > /tmp/pipe 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could happen if you did not enable alpha feature-gate for the option.

Did you set `--feature-gates` option for [kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/)?

```
--feature-gates mapStringBool  - A set of key=value pairs that describe feature gates for alpha/experimental features. Options are:
...
ExpandPersistentVolumes=true|false (ALPHA - default=false)
...
```

Update: If you don't see this option in the command line arguments, you need to add it (`--feature-gates=ExpandPersistentVolumes=true`).

In case you run kube-apiserver as a pod, you should edit /`etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` and add the feature-gate option to other arguments. kube-apiserver will restart automatically.

In case you run kube-apiserver as a process maintained by systemd, you should edit `kube-apiserver.service` or service options `$KUBE_API_ARGS` in a separate file, and append feature-gate option there. Restart the service with `systemctl restart kube-apiserver.service` command.

After enabling it, you can create a StorageClass object with allowVolumeExpansion option:

```
# kubectl get sc -o yaml --export
apiVersion: v1
items:
- allowVolumeExpansion: true
  apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
  kind: StorageClass
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: 2018-05-23T14:38:43Z
    labels:
      k8s-addon: storage-aws.addons.k8s.io
    name: gp2-2
    namespace: ""
    resourceVersion: "1385"
    selfLink: /apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses/gp2-2
    uid: fe516dcf-5e96-11e8-a86d-42010a9a0002
  parameters:
    encrypted: "true"
    kmsKeyId: arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:<omitted>
    type: gp2
    zone: us-west-2a
  provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
  reclaimPolicy: Delete
  volumeBindingMode: Immediate
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

Comment: I am using Kops, so I would have guessed that it would set the feature-gates argument on the apiserver pods if that was necessary. But looking at my config it appears that has not been done. I updated my question with the arguments being used, and will look into how I can get that set.

Comment: I have noticed that I added the featureGates section in the Kops config under kubelet, when I probably wanted it under kubeApiServer. Testing now.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some suggestions how to add the feature-gate option.

Comment: Do you know where to include the `--feature-gates` and `--admission-control` flags in OpenShift 4? Would it be the kube-apiserver operator rather than pods?